# Previous .ipcc files for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, cellular-carriers, lte

My operator recently pushed a carrier update and it has messed up my 2G/3G/LTE switch, which is vital for my survival in low signal-strength area. So reverting to old settings is only way for me. For that I need older version of Idea Cellular (India)'s IPCC (version 35).

Any information on where can I find old versions of Apple's [itunes version xml](http://itunes.com/version)? Or somehow force iOS to download the previous settings?

Comment: Did you try getting in touch with the operator customer support?

Comment: @NimeshNeema That does not answer my question.